# Why isn't $\frac1{3p} =$ the probability that the strategy of always switching succeeds, given that Monty opens door 2?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

> 40. Consider the Monty Hall problem, except that Monty enjoys opening door 2 more
>     than he enjoys opening door 3, and if he has a choice between opening these two doors, he opens door 2 with probability p, where $1/2 \le  p \le 1$.
>
> To recap: there are three doors, behind one of which there is a car (which you want),
> and behind the other two of which there are goats (which you don't want). Initially,
> all possibilities are equally likely for where the car is. You choose a door, which for concreteness we assume is door 1. Monty Hall then opens a door to reveal a goat, and offers you the option of switching. Assume that Monty Hall knows which door has the
> car, will always open a goat door and offer the option of switching, and as above assume that if Monty Hall has a choice between opening door 2 and door 3, he chooses door 2 with probability p (with $1/2 \le  p \le 1$).
>
> (b) Find the probability that the strategy of always switching succeeds, given that Monty
> opens door 2.

Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Chapter 2, Exercise 40, p 91.

#### My wrong approach

Let $C_i$ be the event that car is behind the door $i$,
$O_i$ be the event that Monty opened door $i$ and $X_i$ be the event that intially I chose door $i$. Here $i=1,2,3$.
$P(O_2|C_1, X_1) = p$
$P(O_2|C_2, X_1) = 0$
$P(O_2|C_3, X_1) = 1$

Now, we are to find $P(C_3|O_2, X_1)$.
$P(C_3|O_2, X_1) = \dfrac{P(O_2|C_3, X_1) . P(C_3|X_1)}{P(O_2|X_1)}$
$= \dfrac{1 . \frac{1}{3}}{p}$
$= \dfrac{1}{3p}$

This is not the correct answer. Can anybody comment on what I am missing in my approach here.

Comment: related — https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4031140

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_i$ be the event that car is behind the door $i$,
$O_i$ be the event that Monty opened door $i$ and $X_i$ be the event that intially I chose door $i$. Here $i=1,2,3$.
$P(O_2|C_1, X_1) = p$
$P(O_2|C_2, X_1) = 0$
$P(O_2|C_3, X_1) = 1$

Now, we are to find $P(C_3|O_2, X_1)$.
$P(C_3|O_2, X_1) = \frac{P(O_2|C_3, X_1) . P(C_3|X_1)}{P(O_2|X_1)}$
$= \frac{P(O_2|C_3, X_1) . P(C_3|X_1)}{P(O_2|C_3, X_1) . P(C_3|X_1) + P(O_2|C_2, X_1) . P(C_2|X_1) + P(O_2|C_1, X_1) . P(C_1|X_1)}$

$= \frac{1 . \frac{1}{3}}{1.\frac{1}{3} + 0.\frac{1}{3} + p.\frac{1}{3}}$
$= \frac{1}{1+p}$

This is the correct answer.

Comment: $\checkmark$ In short: $P(O_2\mid X_1) \neq p = P(O_2\mid C_1, X_1)$  .  Rather, use the law of total probability.

Comment: This also works if $0 \le p \lt \frac12$.  And since $\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{1}{1+p} \le 1$ for all possible $p$ with $0 \le p \le 1$, it is still a good idea to always switch, no matter how biased Monty is and whether or not you know how biased he is.