# Monty hall with $n$ doors and Monty opening $m$ doors

Tags: monty-hall

In [Monty Hall problem generalized to $n$ doors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673078/monty-hall-problem-generalized-to-n-doors), the Monty hall's problem was generalized to $n$ doors with Monty opening $m$ of them, where $m < n - 1$.

The probability of winning by switching is $\frac{n - 1}{n(n - m - 1)}$. I am confused about what the probability of winning by not switching is in this case. Is it $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n - m}$, or $1- \frac{n - 1}{n(n - m - 1)}$?
I think it's $\frac{1}{n}$, but this doesn't seem to incorporate monty opening $M$ doors.

Comment: $m$ doesn't play a role in the probability for not switching.  It does play a role in the probability for switching because it plays a role in counting the unopened, unselected doors.  Should stress that the case $m=n-1$ would be radically different.  Why?

Comment: @lulu For that case you get division by zero with the above formula. I wonder why it doesn't give you zero instead, since if monty opens $m = n-1$ doors, then it means the one you picked has the prize.

Comment: If $m<n-1$ then Monty's opening of $m$ doors tells you absolutely nothing about your selection.  You already knew that there were at least $n-1$ worthless doors you did not select.  But if Monty opens $n$ doors then that tells you *a lot* of information about your selections, so of course your estimate of its probability changes.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning by not switching is just the probability of picking the door with the car at your initial guess.

Since there are $n$ doors, the car is behind one unique door and you only choose one door, the probability of winning without switching is just
$$\frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: That makes sense to me, but after Monty opens $m$ doors, couldn't that possibly change our probability of winning by staying put? I.e., shouldn't the probability of winning by staying now be conditioned on knowing Monty opened $m$ doors that didn't have the prize?

Comment: If you initially go for the strategy of not changing your initial choice, then it doesn't matter what Monty does next.

Comment: But we make a decision whether to switch not *after* Monty opens the $m$ doors.

Comment: Ok, but the order of decision doesn't really matter. You know that Monty will always open $m$ doors with goats. So whether you decide to switch before or after Monty opens the doors, is the same.

Comment: I agree the order doesn't matter. What I'm confused about is it seems what this is saying is that $P(\text{winning by not switching} | \text{monty opens m doors}) = P(\text{winning by not switching})$

Comment: The events $\{$winning by not switching$\}$ and $\{$ Monty opens $m$ doors $\}$ are independent. So the probabilities above are indeed the same. Think like this: You pick a door and by doing that (if you don't switch) it is already established whether you win or not. So it doesn't matter what Monty does next, he can $m$ doors, $1$ door, all doors... If you don't switch, this won't affect your reward.

Comment: In the problem Monty only opens doors he knows have goats and he does not open your door; this does not depend on which door you choose.   So $P(\text{winning by not switching} \mid \text{Monty opens }m\text{ doors}) = P(\text{winning by not switching})$ is correct

Comment: Ah, but the odds *are not* 1 in 3 if a goat door is removed.  The host *can not* open the car door.