# In the Monty Hall problem, why isn't Pr(I switch and win| Monty opens door 2) = 1/2?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I have this [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671238/monty-hall-problem-with-biased-door-selection-probability).
What's wrong with my logic?

Call $S$ the event of winning when I switch. Call $M_i$ the event Monty opens door $i$. WLOG I choose door 1.

$P(S|M_2) = P(S|M_2,D_1)P(D_1) + P(S|M_2,D_3)P(D_3) = 0 + 1 * \frac{1}{2}$

The math comes from this interpretation — given that since Monty opens door 2, there are two possible outcomes: the car is in door 1 or in door 3 so there is a 1/2 chance switching will result in success. This isn't the correct answer. Why isn't this logic correct?

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

The Law of Total Probability will actually state:
$$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(S\mid M_2)&=\mathsf P(S\mid M_2,D_1)\,\mathsf P(D_1\mid M_2)+\mathsf P(S\mid M_2,D_3)\,\mathsf P(D_3\mid M_2)\\[1ex]&=0\cdot\mathsf P(D_1\mid M_2)+1\cdot\mathsf P(D_3\mid M_2)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(D_3\mid M_2)\end{align}$$

(Which is sensible: the conditional probability that switching wins *when* door two is revealed, equals the *conditional* probability that the prise is behind the third door *when* door two has been revealed).

Now when Monty picks door 2, the prise does *not* have an equal probability for being behind door 1 and 3. **There are two possible outcomes, but they are not equally likely.** Monty is more likely to have picked door 2 if the prise is behind door 3 than if it is behind door 1.

However, we can evaluate this by applying Bayes' Theorem ... $$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(D_3\mid M_2)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D_3)\,\mathsf P(M_2\mid D_3)}{\mathsf P(M_2)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D_3)\,\mathsf P(M_2\mid D_3)}{\mathsf P(D_1)\,\mathsf P(M_2\mid D_1)+\mathsf P(D_3)\,\mathsf P(M_2\mid D_3)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{\tfrac 12+1}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{2}{3}\end{align}$$

---

When the prise is behind door 1, Monty may open either door 2 or 3, if we assume he does so without bias:$$\small\mathsf P(M_2\mid D_1)=\dfrac 12$$

When the prise is behind door 3, Monty may only open door 2:$$\small\mathsf P(M_2\mid D_3)=1$$