# Monty Hall: What is the "unconditional probability of success" and "conditional probability of success"?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Can someone explain the highlighted paragraph from Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), p 69? I'm not understanding the subtlety the author is trying to get at. What is the "unconditional probability of success"? How is it not conditional because we're conditioning on what door the car is behind to solve the law of total probability equation. What is the "conditional probability of success"? Are "unconditional probability of success" and "conditional probability of success" the same thing?

> [image]

For the normal Monty Hall problem, it seems that the "unconditional probability of success" and "conditional probability of success" are the same; they output the same number (2/3). But they're different in *op. cit.* Exercise 40, p 91.

> Consider the Monty Hall problem, except that Monty enjoys opening Door
> 2 more than he enjoys opening Door 3, and if he has a choice between
> opening these two doors, he opens Door 2 with probability p, where
> $\frac{1}{2} \leq p \leq 1$.
>
> (a) Find the unconditional probability that the strategy of always switching succeeds (unconditional in the sense that we do not condition on which of Doors 2,3 Monty opens).
>
> (b) Find the probability that the strategy of always switching succeeds, given that Monty opens Door 2.
>
> (c) Find the probability that the strategy of always switching succeeds, given that Monty opens Door 3.

The answer is 2/3 for (a) because $0 \cdot 1/3 + 1 \cdot 1/3 + 1 \cdot 1/3 = 2/3$ by LOTP. Why this answer is the same as the normal Monty Hall problem, where Monty enjoys all three doors equally?

The answer for (b) is $\frac{1}{p+1}$ and for (c) it's $\frac{1}{2-p}$.

Comment: Not sure I'd use those terms, but for the "unconditional" case the writer is just  considering the strategy  "Just switch doors no matter what he says.".  If you had originally taken $\#1$ this has the effect of just giving you *both* doors $\#2$ and $\#3$ so of course it has a $\frac 23$ chance of working.  Note that this strategy is entirely independent of whatever rule Monty uses to choose which of two worthless doors to open.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean here? "If you had originally taken #1 this has the effect of just giving you both doors #2 and #3 so of course it has a 2/3 chance of working."

Comment: I mean exactly what I say (well, presuming that the worthless door Monty opens contains nothing at all).  By switching I get the contents of the other two doors.

Comment: To stress:  I would not really consider these to be two different strategies, since the resultant action is the same in all cases.  To be sure, if Monty plays favorites in his door selection, then your reasoning might be slightly different, though again this is a pretty hollow distinction.  (N.B.  there are variants of the problem in which this distinction matters, but you aren't dealing with those here).

Comment: To illustrate the point:  say Monty will always open $\#2$ if that's an option for him.  Then, if I have chosen $\#1$ and he opens $\#3$ I can be certain that the prize is behind $\#2$.  However if he opens $\#2$ then I have a $\frac 12$ chance of winning whether I switch or not.  Note, of course, that my net probability of success if I blindly switch is still $\frac 23$.

Comment: @lulu I think I get it? The first approach basically says, "We're going to examine the cases in which the car is behind door 1,2, and 3, and switch in all three cases. The probability that we will succeed is 2/3." This is "unconditional" in the sense we examine all three cases. The second approach is saying: what is the probability we will succeed if Monty opens door 2? what is the probability that we will succeed if Monty opens door 3? This is "conditional" in the sense we examine a specific case (whether Monty opens door 2 or door 3). Is that correct? I will read your comments now.

Comment: Sure, that's fine.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much! The example really helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119917/discussion-between-beginner-and-lulu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between unconditional and conditional is that for unconditional, we are conditioning on C, and for conditional, we are conditioning on M. Simply put, the thing being conditioned on is different.

You start by picking door 1, it seems as the problem describes.

```
 |
 |
 v
 _   _   _
| | | | | |
| | | | | |
 -   -   -
 1   2   3
```

1. The unconditional property only depends on C, the event that the car is behind door C, so we have the following, where "car" really means "get car by switching." You'll notice that this has no information about M. That is why it is the same no matter the probability that the host chooses door 2. It's not in the formula. It only depends on where the car was initially placed. Maybe this is not a satisfactory explanation, but let's move on.

$$P(car)=P(car|C_1)P(C_1)+P(car|C_2)P(C_2)+P(car|C_3)P(C_3)\\
=0*\frac 1 3+1*\frac 1 3+1*\frac 1 3=\frac 2 3$$

2. You want to find the probability that switching succeeds, given that Monty opens door 2. Let's draw a tree. Maybe take a minute or so to figure out why it is.

```
                                      prob
                      / car     0     0
          / M2  p     
                      \ no_car  1     p/3
/ C1  1/3 
                      / car     0     0
          \ M3  1-p   
                      \ no_car  1     (1-p)/3

                      / car     1     1/3
- C2  1/3 - M3  1    
                      \ no_car  0     0

                      / car     1     1/3
\ C3  1/3 - M2  1     
                      \ no_car  0     0
```

You want $P(car|M_2)=\frac{P(car, M_2)}{P(M_2)}=\frac{P(car,M_2,C_1)+P(car,M_2,C_2)+P(car,M_2,C_3)}{P(M_2,C_1)+P(M_2,C_2)+P(M_2,C_2)}=\frac{0+0+1/3}{p/3+0+1/3}=\frac{1}{p+1}$

3. Similarly, you want $P(car|M_3)=\frac{P(car, M_3)}{P(M_3)}=\frac{P(car,M_3,C_1)+P(car,M_3,C_2)+P(car,M_3,C_3)}{P(M_3,C_1)+P(M_3,C_2)+P(M_3,C_2)}=\frac{0+1/3+0}{(1-p)/3+1/3+0}=\frac{1}{2-p}$
4. Lastly, we go back to verify that the "conditional probability" of getting the car conditioning on M is the same as the "unconditional probability" of getting a car conditioning on C, which was 2/3 as determined in part 1. We need the law of total probability $P(car)=P(car|M_2)P(M_2)+P(car|M_3)P(M_3)=P(M_2)\frac{1}{p+1}+P(M_3)\frac{1}{2-p}$.

Convince yourself with the following diagram that the $P(M_2)=\frac 1 3+\frac p 3$. That is, again $P(M_2)=P(M_2,C_1)+P(M_2,C_2)+P(M_2,C_3)=P(M_2|C_1)P(C_1)+P(M_2|C_2)P(C_2)+P(M_2|C_3)P(C_3)=1*\frac 1 3+0*\frac 1 3+p*\frac 1 3=\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3 p$. Alternatively, you could have used the huge tree above. Since opening door 3 is the complement to opening door 2, $P(M_3)=1-P(M_2)=1-\left(\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3p\right)$. Now you can finally find the "conditional" probability that you win a car by switching:

$$\left(\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3p\right)\frac{1}{p+1}+\left(1-\left(\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3p\right)\right)\frac{1}{2-p}=\frac 2 3$$

```
  _
|[ ]| [ ] [c]
|[ ]| [c] [ ]
|[c]| [ ] [ ]
  -
```

It is the same as the "unconditional" probability conditioning on C instead of M.

Comment: I would say what makes $P(car)$ an unconditional probability is it is **not** conditioned on $C.$ It's true you can compute it by a sum involving conditional probabilities, but this does not make it a conditional probability, any more than you can say that $8$ is an odd number because it is the sum of $3$ and $5$, which are odd numbers.

Comment: 1. Can you please rename "Car", which befuddled me, to S (for switching and winning) or W (winning by switching)? Because you wrote, and intended to write that, *""car" really means "get car by switching"*. 2. Can you please explain your top and bottom pictures typed in backtick `, and backgrounded in gray? What are you trying to picture?

Comment: 3. Your answer contains typos. See [Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34431), or my rejected [Suggested Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1725174).

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer, rather than comment. Comments can get deleted.